# How to run the ci checks only on merge queue in github

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm working on integrating GitHub's new Merge Queues feature into our workflow. As I understand, currently, the CI checks for required PRs are executed both on the actual PRs and again on the merge queue. This seems redundant and resource-intensive. Is there a way to configure GitHub so that the CI checks only run on the merge queues and not on each individual PR?

Additionally, I'm looking for a method to enable Merge Queues across multiple repositories via GitHub's API. Manually configuring each repository is not feasible for our scale. I couldn't find relevant documentation or API endpoints that support this. Does anyone know if this is possible and how it can be implemented?

Comment: How did you implement your Github Action workflow, could you share the YAML file? Using the [merge_group](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#merge_group) trigger should work here. There is a nice article about this process [here](https://medium.com/@kojoru/how-to-set-up-merge-queues-in-github-actions-59381e5f435a) if you want to have a look.